# Does hidden component in react native send request to server?

Tags: react-native, request

I wonder how react native works if component is hidden. For example in this code

```
{visible && <RkModalImg rkCardImg renderFooter={this._renderHeader} source={{ uri: PhotoURL }} />}
```

If visible variable is equal to `false` does it send request to server ?

Comment: If you aren't rendering a component then that component will not exist so it's functions will not be executed

Answer (score 0):

In general in javascript, if you do this:

`const x = b && b.name // this means if b has value execute b.names otherwaise x will be null`

in your case, the component will not get rendered which means it will not execute anything(component doesn't exist).